# Infopath: Set values of repeating tables based on previous input

Tags: infopath, default-value

I hope this is the right place for my question...

Basically, I have an InfoPath form with a repeating section that has some dropdown fields and text boxes. What I want to achieve is that the default value of a dropdown field becomes the last value entered.

For example, in every section there is a dropdown field for a "responsible person". It is possible, that there are different responsible persons in different sections, but it is very likely that the next section will have the same responsible person as the previous one.

So I want to pre populate the next "responsible person" dropdown field - as soon as it is created by adding a new section - with the last value the user entered in a "responsible person" dropdown field.

I already thought about creating an invisible field and setting a rule on the "responsible person" dropdown field that changes this fields value whenever one dropdown changes. But I struggle with finding a solution on how to copy that value to the newly created dropdown field.

Is there a way to achieve that? Maybe with another approach as mine? Preferably without coding, as I'd have to order Visual Studio first and that takes an awful lot of time...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... It is when you think about how to write down your question, that you actually start finding a solution. Somehow it slipped my mind so far now. 
It's the easiest one there is: Just set the invisible field as default value for the dropdown field and untick the "update value" Checkbox. For some reason I thought the default value wouldn't Change according to the invisible fields value when unticked. But it does.